# BigQuery NOT EXISTS... NOT EQUAL TO (!=) and EXISTS... EQUAL TO Giving Different Results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am lost and trying to figure out the reason I am getting different outputs for the same logic. I want to find out all calls (variants and non-variants) for each call set, and omits any call with a non-PASS filter.

The query is given at the [link](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/tutorials/analyze-variants-advanced#counting_high-quality_variants_per_sample):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  call.name AS call_name,
  COUNT(1) AS number_of_calls
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.human_genome_variants.platinum_genomes_deepvariant_variants_20180823` v, v.call
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(call.FILTER) AS call_filter WHERE call_filter != 'PASS')
GROUP BY
  call_name
ORDER BY
  call_name
```

| Row | call_name | number_of_calls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA12877 | 29795946 |
| 2 | NA12878 | 26118774 |
| 3 | NA12889 | 29044992 |
| 4 | NA12890 | 28717437 |
| 5 | NA12891 | 31395995 |
| 6 | NA12892 | 25349974 |

This returns the number of rows that have filter as PASS.

But, when I try a similar logic I get a different result.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  call.name AS call_name,
  COUNT(1) AS number_of_calls
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.human_genome_variants.platinum_genomes_deepvariant_variants_20180823` v, v.call
WHERE
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(call.FILTER) AS call_filter WHERE call_filter = 'PASS')
GROUP BY
  call_name
ORDER BY
  call_name
```

| Row | call_name | number_of_calls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA12877 | 4488086 |
| 2 | NA12878 | 4503443 |
| 3 | NA12889 | 4423974 |
| 4 | NA12890 | 4529950 |
| 5 | NA12891 | 4425316 |
| 6 | NA12892 | 4497085 |

Why is this? Is my logic wrong? Can someone explain why empty array is a "PASS" in this case? Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: The first would be true if filter is an empty list.

Comment: @shawnt00, thank you so much! It seems empty array ([]) is setting the where condition to TRUE. Therefore, the excess counts. Do you know why empty array makes the not exists to TRUE?

Comment: No such row exists therefore the condition is still met. You asked for non-existence and you got it! I've never been to New York but every time I went I didn't see the Statue of Liberty.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @shawnt00 for providing the solution.
I will demonstrate with a few smaller examples that the extra counts are indeed empty arrays.
Query 1

```
with smalltable as (
    select ["PASS"] as filter, 'NA12877' as name union all 
    select ["PASS"], 'NA12877' union all 
    select ["PASS"], 'NA12879' union all 
    select ["PASS",'RefCall'], 'NA12877' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12877' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12877' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12879' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12879' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12879' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12879', union all
    select [], 'NA12879'   
)
select name, count(1) as count 
from smalltable 
where not exists (select 1 from unnest(filter) as f where f != 'PASS')
group by name
```

Output:

| Row | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA12877 | 2 |
| 2 | NA12879 | 2 |

As we can see the query considers [] as 'PASS'. I am not sure why?

Query 2

```
with smalltable as (
    select ["PASS"] as filter, 'NA12877' as name union all 
    select ["PASS"], 'NA12877' union all 
    select ["PASS"], 'NA12879' union all 
    select ["PASS",'RefCall'], 'NA12877' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12877' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12877' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12879' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12879' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12879' union all 
    select ["RefCall"], 'NA12879', union all
    select [], 'NA12879'   
)
select name, count(1) as count 
from smalltable 
where exists (select 1 from unnest(filter) as f where f = 'PASS')
group by name
```

Output:

| Row | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA12877 | 3 |
| 2 | NA12879 | 1 |

This as expected does not count the empty array.